# Select on complicated a tag with Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, select

I am trying to click on an "a-tag" n a web page using selenium.
Basically my objective is to click on that button which will redirect me on another webpage.
The a-tag looks as follows:

```
<a class="SheetInfoLink xl35" href="/ux/WebReport/tabbedsummarypage.aspx?itemId=118685&amp;lType=modData&amp;compId=1002&amp;showTabs=" onclick="javascript:spSPGetModData('118685', '1002' ,'', 'modData');return false;" style="border:0px">Zolgensma</a>
```

I am using something likee this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://app.evaluate.com/ux/WebReport/tabbedsummarypage.aspx?itemId=10&lType=modData&compId=1006&tabId=")
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@data-trackable='sign-in']")
button.click()
```

but it does not work.
Any suggeestion?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with `explicit wait` :

**code :**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href, '/ux/WebReport/tabbedsummarypage.aspx') and text() ='Zolgensma']"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: That's an explicit wait, read more about explicit wait here - https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html